# Quick Suggestion setting in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to programming and learning python in VS Code, every time I type "pr", "print" will come automatically but how to change "Print" with "Print()".

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can change it to say `print()` in User and Workspace Settings (in settings.json) when in the middle of typing the word. It's doing that because of its auto-complete setting.

Comment: I think you have better luck with snippets: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, smart suggestions will only give the function name without parentheses.

Add the following configuration to **settngs.json** to enable the feature of automatically adding parentheses to functions.

```
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
```

[image]